# Possible to Authenticate an incoming Webhook for use with Post REST Service

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps, httppost, webhooks

Still new to working with REST services and apex in general. I have put together a simple REST Service for inserting records with JSON delivered via HTTPPost. Everything works great when I use workbench.developerforce.com to send JSON via post. When I try to send actual data via the third-party webhook I get no record insertions.

I'm fairly certain this is because I haven't told Salesforce it's ok to receive post data from my external source. If I'm understanding correctly I either need to expose my REST service to the public using a force.com site or by using an OAuth flow.

I'd prefer to not have my REST service just publicly available as I wrote it specifically for this single third-party and they should be the only ones using it. However, they are sending data via webhooks, and I have very limited control over them. I can only specify a Payload URL (currently set to my REST service URL) as well as a "Request Header" (which they say will be "included as a value in the POST request's header").

Is it possible to send the necessary info via the post request header to authenticate or do I need to set up a Connected app? If I use a connected app do I point the third-party webhook to a login URL with consumer keys and credentials in the header and then set the callback URL to the REST Service?

Any suggestions or general guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your remote service sending messages that can be authenticated in the fashion common among webhooks (transmitting the hash of the message plus a pre-shared secret key)?

Comment: @DavidReed I'm unsure. How could I tell? Is there documentation on this set up anywhere?

Comment: I'm thinking of the way [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#delivery-headers) can do it - unfortunately, their doc here is not as thorough as it might be, but it's basically an HMAC message authentication code with a key your systems share. It lets you authenticate that messages to a public endpoint come from a sender that knows that key. Applicable only if your remote system actually supports that.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction @DavidReed. I'm guessing it's not the most secure way, but for now I've added a custom header to the third-party webhook and I check for it at the beginning of my HttpPost.

Answer (score 3):

The best secure way would be to use a [Connected App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPOLjnxeuF4) and [Server-Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) flow

It is always better to authenticate to Salesforce and reach into Salesforce using a connected app.

However, as you pointed that if you do not have a lot of control then you need a proxy server doing this for you.

One approach would be to use a [Heroku Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/integrating-heroku-and-salesforce) app and exposing that to a public endpoint.

This app can look for certain headers and then authenticate and securely store all the credentials required to reach into Salsforce.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that using the JWT Bearer Flow (server to server) still essentially requires two calls to my salesforce server? The first sends over the JWT and SF then returns an access token. Then I would need to send that access token via my post header request to the REST service?

Comment: correct! Watch the video link I have there that technically will explain all you need to set up a connection and authenticate. Security is hard :)

Comment: Why use Heroku when you can do all of that in Apex, right here on the same platform ;-)

Comment: Some cloud apps you just have to add the public hook endpoint! With apex if you expose as a public site it can be hit by anyone! With Heroku server you can filter only appropriate calls by looking at the header!

Comment: Note that as per requirement, you have no control over external system! If that system can control then it would make lot of sense to reach into Salesforce directly!

Comment: I ended up taking David Reed's suggestion as a quick workaround. I was able to add a custom header:value to the httppost that I can check for on my publicly exposed REST to ensure it's legitimate before taking any actions. I know this is probably not near as safe as using JWT, but for now, I think it will suffice.

Comment: It works for now but if someone hacks it up then there will be unnecessary api consumptions! Just something to be aware of

Comment: Related issue I think; I'm getting 'insufficient access rights on cross-reference id' errors now. Is it not possible to insert/update records via the publicly available rest service? I've ensured read/write access to the fields on the objects I'm working with and made sure my apex class is available to the Guest User, but every time I try to insert or update a record I get the error.

Comment: It is definitely possible! Make sure all related object can be accessed as well! Check for triggers and record type access and so on!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I think I'm misunderstanding. Do I need to give access to every object that is related to the object I'm trying to update/create regardless of whether or not I'm setting those corresponding lookup fields? In my case, I'm trying to create a Lead record, so I would need to grant the Guest User access to User, Individual, and Group objects?

Comment: Can you try using without sharing in your apex code? If yes then yes it could be access issue